# Why don't SQL queries on Snowflake suffer from floating point inaccuracy?

Tags: sql, floating-accuracy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8), a `FLOAT` is a double-precision (64 bit) IEEE 754 floating point number. This is the norm. Python, for example, also implements floats this way, and consequently suffers from floating point accuracy issues with certain values. Consider,

```
nRooks$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0.3 + 0.6
0.8999999999999999
```

LiteSQL also gives me the value `0.8999999999999999` for the query `select CAST(0.3 AS FLOAT) + CAST(0.6 AS FLOAT)`. All as expected.

**HOWEVER**, I get a strange result from the following query in a Snowflake worksheet:

```
select (0.3::float + 0.6::float)::float

Row           (0.3::FLOAT + 0.6::FLOAT)::FLOAT
1             0.9
```

Simplifying the query to `select 0.6 + 0.3` does not alter the result. Why is it returning `.9` instead of the expected `0.8999999999999999`?

Comment: Maybe they are simply using a different library or internal representation that makes it more accurate? Postgres and Oracle also return 0.9

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That was my initial assumption, but then the Snowflake docs (https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#float-float4-float8) say that they implement FLOAT IEEE 754 style.

Comment: Perhaps they round when they print the value?

Comment: The printed value is rounded for display; it is not the actual value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Further experiments have made it clear that you are correct, thanks!

Comment: @seisvelas can you post your code which clarifies this as an answer to your question? Might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Like others suspected, this is a text formatting issue.

Snowflake supports various ways of formatting numbers, see e.g. [here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#text-minimal-numeric-formats). So depending on the format used, you will see different values, for example:

```
-- Will round the value
select to_varchar(0.3::float + 0.6::float, '9.999999');
-------------------------------------------------+
 TO_VARCHAR(0.3::FLOAT + 0.6::FLOAT, '9.999999') |
-------------------------------------------------+
  0.9                                            |
-------------------------------------------------+

-- Enough decimal digits to print without rounding
select to_varchar(0.3::float + 0.6::float, '9.9999999999999999');
-----------------------------------------------------------+
 TO_VARCHAR(0.3::FLOAT + 0.6::FLOAT, '9.9999999999999999') |
-----------------------------------------------------------+
  0.8999999999999999                                       |
-----------------------------------------------------------+

-- "text minimal" format without exponent
select to_varchar(0.3::float + 0.6::float, 'tm9');
--------------------------------------------+
 TO_VARCHAR(0.3::FLOAT + 0.6::FLOAT, 'TM9') |
--------------------------------------------+
 0.8999999999999999                         |
--------------------------------------------+

-- "text minimal" format with exponent
select to_varchar(0.3::float + 0.6::float, 'tme');
--------------------------------------------+
 TO_VARCHAR(0.3::FLOAT + 0.6::FLOAT, 'TME') |
--------------------------------------------+
 8.999999999999999e-1                       |
--------------------------------------------+
```

Note, this formatting is mostly used on the server side (hence explicit cast `TO_VARCHAR`) - different clients might format floating point values differently.